# How to access properties object in spring

Tags: spring

We are heavily using spring in 20 something batch jobs with overrides from properties file. Those 20 something jobs are deployed in 7-8 war files.

In each war, we would like to display properties being used during runtime.

Is there anyway we can get access to final properties object built by spring container so that we can loop though each property name and display on jsp page?

Answer (score 0):

spring-boot-actuator provides a REST endpoint that returns all loaded properties. If you cannot use that directly, have a look at class

```
org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.EnvironmentEndpoint
```

there you can see how you can get all configured properties of the environment.